# How to filter youtube video viewCount in ascending order

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

By using PHP i can get the videos by view like this

```
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->setVideoQuery('');
$query->setOrderBy('viewCount');
$feed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query->getQueryUrl(2));
```

This will give the videoFeed in the **Descending Order**, Is there any way to get the videoFeed in **"ascending order"**

Comment: I don't believe this is currently supported by the API. If your video results are small you could reverse the order yourself before displaying; however this isn't realistic if you've got multiple pages of results unless you want to do all the calls at once for all of your 'previous' and 'next' pages.

Comment: @jlmcdonald thanks what does it mean $query->setOrderBy('viewCount');

Comment: That's the command that your PHP library is using to set the "orderby" parameter to return them in order of the number of views the videos have. If you were just calling the URLs yourself, it would be akin to having "?orderby=viewCount" as part of the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something that's natively supported in the YouTube Data API. You're only option would be to request as many results as are publicly available and then sorting client-side.